Is there an easy way to get Python CLI command suggestions when the user misspells something?
I'm making a large command line tool with Typer (a wrapper on Click), and I was wondering how to provide a little help blurb when a user uses an invalid command, something like so:
$ cmd builld
Oops, the command "builld" is not valid. Did you mean:
    build
    build-other
    beta build

I found some projects like thefuzz, https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz, but there isn't any documentation for actually making this work. Thanks!
Edit: minimal typer thingy,
import typer

app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def foo(name: str):
    """Print a greeting message"""
    typer.echo(f"Hello, {name}!")

@app.command()
def bar(count: int):
    """Print a message multiple times"""
    for i in range(count):
        typer.echo(f"Bar {i+1}!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()


well you can always check out the argument which are given, and in your code you can have this work check functionality , which might be a overkill in my opinion

Hi, could you please provide minimal working example of your code written with Typer?

This question may be useful for you.
